# Debugging native c++ threads

Tags: android, debugging, native-code

I have developed some c++ libraries and now I want to use it in android, but I have a problem, I'm not able to debug this libraries on android, I have tried with  Sequoyah plugin for eclipse, I have tried connect directly agains gdb server into the device, but I can't.

I'm using Sony Ericsson Xperia arc lt15i and Android 2.3.3, so in theory I must be able to debug the natives threads.

Any idea or help? Someone have been able to debugged natives threads?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you read this:
wiki.eclipse.org/Sequoyah/ndk_guide